# Passar diversos atributos no django

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django

Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Eu estou iniciando os meus estudos em django e encontro um problema. Eu tenho uma função na minha view com o seguinte trecho

```
def saldo_total(request):
    receitas = Receitas.objects.aggregate(Sum('valor'))
    total_receitas = receitas['valor__sum']
    despesas = Despesas.objects.aggregate(Sum('valor'))
    total_despesas = despesas['valor__sum']

    receitas = receitas['valor__sum']
    despesas = despesas['valor__sum']

    total = total_receitas - total_despesas

    return render(request, 'financas/saldo_total.html', {'total': total}, {'receitas': receitas}, {'despesas': despesas})
```

ele faz uma busca no db fazendo o somatório das receitas e despesas, e também mais abaixo, subtrai um pelo outro para informar o saldo disponível do usuário.

Porém, o render só me permite jogar um atributo ao retorno e eu gostaria que os três fossem retornados.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso no django?

Answer (score 0):

Sim. O que você bota no `render` é um dicionário, e dicionários podem conter mais de um par chave/valor.

O que quer é equivalente ao seguinte:

```
return render(request, 'financas/saldo_total.html', {'total': total, 'receitas': receitas, 'despesas': despesas})
```

Ou, de um jeito mais organizado:

```
dados = {'total': total, 
         'receitas': receitas,
         'despesas': despesas }
return render(request, 'financas/saldo_total.html', dados)
```

Comment: Obrigado, amigo. Funcionou perfeitamente.